# npm install doesn't work with --save-dev option on windows 8

Tags: windows, powershell, npm

On my windows8 I tried to install a npm package

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

if I run it without --save-dev it works perfectly

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

adding saving couses an error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\2\package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\2\package.json'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: 'C:\\2\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
 "install" "grunt-contrib-uglify" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd C:\2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\2\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\2\package.json'
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\2\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\2\npm-debug.log'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: 'C:\\2\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
 "install" "grunt-contrib-uglify" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd C:\2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\2\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\2\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\2\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've checked files permissions, I've ran it as Administrator. I cannot find a way to get it working.

Please, help ;)

Comment: Can you add details to your question about how you ran it as Administrator?

Comment: Can you edit that file (package.json) with a different program (ie notepad) also as an administrator - if not your problem is not with node.js but rather Windows permissions.

Comment: The project was created via Yeoman. Both package.json and bower.json had "read only" attribute, so even the permissions to the file were ok, it could not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue on OSX, I fixed it executing:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
```

and:

```
npm cache clean
```

Then I can install the package with --save-dev in the project.

In your case, instead of using `chown` you can change the permissions on "C:\2" and subfolders to your user using the Windows Explorer, i.e: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx Or directly from PowerShell: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder.aspx

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5869

Comment: thanks. As I wrote in the to the first post - the read only attribute was a problem.